# float INFINITY can be archived by NSCoder, but not dearchived

Tags: ios, objective-c, archiving

I have to archive a `float` with value `INFINITY`, and later to dearchive it.
Here is my example code:

Object to be archived:

```
@interface CodeInf : NSObject <NSCoding>
@end
@implementation CodeInf
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    float inf = INFINITY;
    [encoder encodeFloat: inf forKey:@"INFINITY"];
}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        float decodedInf = [decoder decodeFloatForKey: @"INFINITY"];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

And here is the archiving/dearchiving code:

```
CodeInf *myCodeInf = [[CodeInf alloc] init];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myCodeInf];
myCodeInf = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Archiving works, but dearchiving raises the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeFloatForKey:]: value (inf) for
>   key (INFINITY) too large to fit in 32-bit float'

Is this a bug in the dearchiver, or do I something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug. Submit a bug report to Apple.

As a workaround use `encodeDouble` and `decodeDoubleForKey` - you can keep your value as a `float` and no casts are needed by C rules.

Comment: Thanks CRD, I will submit a bug report, and your workaround is fine!

Comment: Hey, @ReinhardMänner did you submit a bug report and what is the link? We just faced similar crash on iOS 8.3 with encoding/decoding float value. Thanks!

Comment: @Danik: I filed a bug report June 12, 2013, but never got an answer and it is still open. The reference number is 14126397. Is this the "link" that you asked for? Or how can I get a link to this report?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner thanks! Just filed another report with id 20916424

Comment: Ran into this as well. Still not fixed!