# Encoding CGSize with infinite dimension using NSKeyedArchiver fails

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to store a `CGSize` in `UserDefaults`. The size can have a width or height of `CGFloat.infinity`. I put the size into a `NSValue` and encode and decode it using `NSKeyedArchiver`:

```
let size = CGSize(width: CGFloat.infinity, height: 50)
let value = NSValue(cgSize: size)

let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value)
let unarchivedValue = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! NSValue
```

Problem: The unarchived size is wrong when one of the dimensions is `.infinity`:

```
print(size == value.cgSizeValue)  // true
print(size == unarchivedValue.cgSizeValue)  // false

print(size)  // width: inf, height: 50.0
print(unarchivedValue.cgSizeValue)  // width: 50.0, height: 0.0
```

Note that weirdly enough, the width has the value that was previously the height.

Same results for `Double.infinity`.

Comment: I would suggest to file a bug report at Apple.

Comment: I will. For anyone stumbling on this, Alex pointed me to this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059941

Comment: Possible duplicate of [float INFINITY can be archived by NSCoder, but not dearchived](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059941/float-infinity-can-be-archived-by-nscoder-but-not-dearchived)

Answer (score 1):

You can save CGSize into a string instead:

```
let size = CGSize(width: CGFloat.infinity, height: 50)
let sizeString = NSStringFromCGSize(size)
let decodedSize = CGSizeFromString(sizeString)
```

This will restore 0 instead of infinity, but height and width are not getting messed up.

Comment: Still wondering why this issue exists in the first place. Is it a bug in the decoding process or is `infinity` not intended to be used with `CGSize`?

Comment: I suppose the problem is not about using infinity in CGSize, but rather in archiving float infinity using NSKeyedArchiver. It seems like infinity value doesn't fit in 32-bit

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for the link!

Comment: You're welcome. Still I'd recommend to stick with NSStringFromCGSize approach. It is shorter and more reliable.